# Problems refreshing DataGridView after database update in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
 Dim myQuery = "UPDATE table1 SET data= CONCAT (data,'" & vbCrLf & "[ " &       Date.Now() & " ]" & " " & "[" & getCN() & "]" & " " & txtTelenotes.Text & "[ item1 ]" & "') WHERE id='" & txtID.Text & "'"
 myCommand.Connection = conn
 myCommand.CommandText = myQuery

 myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
 Dim myData As MySqlDataReader
 myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

 txtTelenotes.Text = ""
 dgvREcord.Refresh()
```

I tried refreshing the DataGridView using:

```
  dgvREcord.Refresh()
```

but it does not load the changes from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Close your data connection and re-open it.

I have a similar app but use tableadapters instead so mine looks like:

```
    Me.VictimsTableAdapter.Dispose()
    Me.VictimsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.VicsDataSet.Victims)
```